# the evolution of spin in the Heisenberg picture of Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

> Assuming that the operators σi describe the component i of the spin
>   observable for a spin- 1 2 particle, and assuming this particle to be
>   immersed in a time-independent magnetic field B~ such that the
>   Hamiltonian of the system is given by
>
> ```
>                     H = − µ σ · B,
> ```
>
> with µ > 0 a real constant, show that, in the Heisenberg picture of
>   time evolution, the evolution equation for the operator σi,H(t) is
>   given in 3-vector form compactly by
>
> $\frac{d \sigma_{H}}{dt} = \frac{-2 \mu}{h} B \times \sigma_{H}$

I know I have to  have  to use

$ \frac{d}{dt} A(t)_{H} = \frac{i}{h}[H , A(t)_{H}] + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}A(t)]_{H} $

So I get $ \frac{d}{dt} \sigma_{H}(t)_{i} = \frac{i}{h} [ H, \sigma_{H}(t)_{i}]$

= $ [H\sigma_{H}(t)_{i} - \sigma_{H}(t)_{i} H ]$

From here,

$ H U^{+} \sigma_{i} U - U^{+} \sigma_{i} U H$

= $ U^{+} [H , \sigma_{i}]U $

Dont know how to proceed from here, any help appreciated!

Comment: Heisenberg loved the Baby Blue.

Comment: Well you need to insert the definition of H for one thing, also you are missing the partial derivative term

Comment: Hi! I just found your question. Any chance you can provide some insights on my identical question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/579082/heisenberg-equation-of-motion-why-is-vec-sigma-h-vec-sigma